# How to specifying yerrorbar style from gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

emphasized textPlotting script that used to work for the previous version of gnuplot 
(v4.2.6) no longer work for the latest version (v4.4.0) and produces 
error messages for the following script line.

```
plot "data_file" u ($1+0.5):2 title "legend1" w boxes fs solid 0.85,
"" u ($1+0.5):2:3 notitle w yerrorbars 1, 
....
```

The error goes away as I change *"yerrorbars 1" to "yerrorbars"*.
However, this prohibits the customization of  the errorbar style. 
Can anyone tell me how can I do this right?

---

I'm attaching test code that causes the error and the error message.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/gnuplot
set term postscript monochrome enhanced
set output "test.eps"
set grid x y
set xtics nomirror
set ytics 1.5 font "Helvetica, 18"
set yrange [0:10]
set xrange [0:10]
set boxwidth 1
set bmargin 3
set key top left

plot "test.dat" u ($1+0.5):2 title "test0"  \
        w boxes fs solid 0.85,              \
        "" u ($1+0.5):2:3 notitle w yerrorbars 1,     \
        "" u ($1+1.5):4 title "test1" w boxes fs solid 0.7, \
        "" u ($1+1.5):4:5 notitle w yerrorbars 1
```

I ran above script with the following data.

```
$ cat test.dat
1       1.315119617     0.131   1.199138756     0.136
7       5.382161114     0.002   4.818144427     0.003
```

and it generated the following error messages.

```
$ gnuplot test.plt

    plot "test.dat" 
....
^ "test.plt", line 17: ';' expected
```

As I mentioned from above, the error goes away when I change ***yerrorbar 1*** to ***yerrorbar*** but this prevent me from specifying error bar style.

Comment: Please post the error that you get when you run your script above.

Comment: I just updated the question to have sample code and data. Thanks for your interested!

Comment: It is unclear to me, how you can specify a yerrorbar style. To my knowledge there is only [this](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/style-e.html#errorbars) style. Could you point out what style you are after?

Comment: @kjee Is any of the answer below sufficient for you?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what `set bars 1` does?

Answer (score 1):

The style of error bars depends on the linestyle which is being used for the plot. So you should specify it like this:

```
plot "mydata.csv" linestyle 1 with yerrorbars
```

**linestyle 1** is what you need

Answer (score 1):

*nblumoe* is about the specific style. You can also affect other characteristics, for instance

```
plot "mydata.csv" linestyle 1 linewidth 2 with yerrorbars
```